# Why is a try catch statement required?

Tags: java, try-catch, sleep, interrupted-exception, timeunit

Why is a try/catch exception handling statement required in Java for the below line:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250);
```

I just want my code to sleep for 250 milliseconds before executing the next line. Why is a try-catch statement required? I can’t forsee any exceptions with this. The sleep function in python doesn't require a try catch.

The exception I get in the IDE without adding the try catch is:

```
Error:(124, 40) error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

When I surround it in the try catch as per below it works fine:

```
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception simply because the thread running (sleeping) might be interrupted and you need to catch the interruption.

From the [Oracle description of the InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html)

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupting a thread that is sleeping is a very important part of Java.  It provides control when you need to stop an application (or a process) and do not want to be halted from doing so due a thread sleeping.  The InterruptException allows developers to catch interrupt attempts and deal with it.

Maybe your beef is with checked exceptions in general.... which is a feature of Java that many people do not like.  We can understand your frustration with checked exceptions.  You can read up more on checked exceptions in Java via Google.